# Magento 2: Multistore url not working in Nginx

Tags: magento2

i have create two website in magento single instance. For second website i have create new folder in root for accessing second website using this url `www.domain.com/site2/` and inside this folder i have added `inder.php , pub, lib, app, var symilnk.`

I have use Nginx server so when i tried to access this folder then its showing 404 page so not able to access this new folder '`site2/`'

is there any idea how can i access this folder for access another website.

Comment: Did you change settings in backend to point base secure and not secure URL to www.domain.com/site2/ for your second scope?

Comment: yes i have done this setting but not able to access this folder. may be is there need to do the changes in nginx.conf.samle file but its not applied which is available in magento root folder.